# Solving PDE with D'Alembert's Formula for $x >0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I am working on solving a PDE with the wave equation and d'Alembert's formula, where there is a boundary condition. I am supposed to use an odd reflection of the wave equation. The IVP is

$$u_{tt}-u_{xx}=0, x>0, t>0$$
$$u(0,t)=0,  t>0$$
$$u(x, 0)=0, x>0$$
$$u_t(x, 0)=p(x)$$, where $p(x)=
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x, 0\le x\le1 \\ 
0, \text{otherwise} \\ 
\end{array}
\right. 
$

I think there are 2 cases: $x \ge t\gt 0$ and $t\ge x\gt 0$, and I know that the first case could be solved with the regular d'Alembert formula, and the second case needs the odd reflection, making it 
$$u(x,t)=\frac12 \int_{t-x}^{x+t} p(s)ds$$ because $u(x,0)=0$. I just do not know where to go from here. Any help would be appreciated!!!

Comment: I don't understand your question. You stated you know how to use d'Alembert's formula, and you wrote down the answer. What more do you want help with?

Comment: @WillieWong I guess my question is do i need to do any more than this. If i have the formula for p(x) do i need to do anything to solve the integral, or do i need to combine the cases to somehow get a full answer for u(x,t)

Comment: Ah, if this is for a homework assignment, you will need to ask your instructor. As written your response is "correct", but may not be "detailed enough" to receive credit in your course.